# Is it possible to add a SharePoint Addin to MS Teams like an azure app

Tags: sharepoint-addin, microsoft-teams

We want to build a SharePoint Hosted Add-in but we want it to be hosted in MS teams.

We know we can add an Azure app to Teams, but if it's possible we want to build it as a SharePoint Add-in and not as an azure app.

The other option would be to create a Provider Hosted Add-in, but that would still require a server to host the app.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to just show the SharePoint add-in on MS Teams Channels? If yes, you can use MS Teams Tab Conversations option by adding the SharePoint add-in to your Site Collection and copying the URL, and configuring it on MS Teams Channel Tab conversations as a web page.

Comment: I found this, but there are some problems like the authentication where you have to login to the tab and also some javascript won't work

Comment: If you are aware, you can wrap your client side app (if JS based) with MS Teams Apps. The documentation can be found on getting started with MS Teams app here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/overview

Comment: I tried that but I got some "MSteams" is undefined errors 
I will keep researching on that

Comment: Extremely sorry for late reply, If you can provide more details what you did and where it failed that will help us identifying the gap and providing right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to crate the addin and import it to Teams using the WebPage tab